# Get type with value_type in pertect forward

Tags: c++, type-traits, perfect-forwarding

I create a function which perfect forward into this function:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void push_back_3(T&& container) {
  using containter_val_type = typename T::value_type;
  containter_val_type val = 3;
  container.emplace_back(val);
}
```

The function can accept container input, such as `std::vector`, `std::list`...

I know above `std` container has implement type-trait `value_type` .

So I just use `std::vector<T>::value_type` or `std::list<T>::value_type` ,

I'll get type `T`.

then

I demo program:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> ivec{1,2,3,4};
  push_back_3(ivec);
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = ivec.begin(); 
        iter != ivec.end(); 
        ++iter) 
  {
    std::cout << *iter << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But I got error message:

```
> $ clang++ t.cc -o t                                                               
t.cc:11:40: error: type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > &' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
  using containter_val_type = typename T::value_type;
                                       ^
t.cc:18:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'push_back_3<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > &>' requested here
  push_back_3(ivec);
  ^
1 error generated.
```

I don't know why I got above error.

Comment: Notice that we now have for range: `for (int e : ivec) { std::cout << e << "\n"; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is deduced to be *lvalue* reference, you have to remove reference by:

```
typename std::decay_t<T>::value_type;
```

Forwarding reference for lvalue (this is such case, because `ivec` is named object) returns `T&`. There is no way to get `value_type` for reference type.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/498PiR)

Comment: Hi @rafix07 Does `push_back_3(T&& container)` still zero cost if I use `std::decay_t<T>`

Comment: If `T` is deduced to be *rvalue* reference, Does this code still work fine?

Comment: @curlywei Calling this function for pure rvalue doesn't make any sense, because you will change temporary instance of vector. But sure, you can call `push_back3(std::move(ivec))` and modyfing vector by rvalue reference but then it is **very misleading**. Here is link [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/mNWBQM) with rvalue, dont do this in such way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in perfect forwarding here, why bother adding elements to a container that is going to die at the `}`?

Take a lvalue reference, then `T` is the correct type

```
template<typename T>
void push_back_3(T& container) {
  using containter_val_type = typename T::value_type;
  containter_val_type val = 3;
  container.emplace_back(val);
}
```

Aside: you are *copying* into the argument of `emplace_back`, you might as well

```
template<typename T>
void push_back_3(T& container) {
  container.emplace_back(3);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to pass container into function with 0-cost

Comment: lvalue references are also 0 cost. You *don't need* to `push_back_3` into an rvalue container, and you *weren't* maintaining the passed in value category when you were using `container`

Comment: So, if the object I pass into ` push_back_3` which can be modify, then use`lvalue reference`. if the object I pass into `push_back_3` just temporary object, use `rvalue reference`, right?

Comment: There's *no point* in `push_back_3`ing a **temporary**, because *by definition* it's about to cease to exist, along with all it's elements.